# Two questions I am asking about that one is what is the subject of the sentence, another is why is a comma between flytrap and drop

Tags: grammar

To feed the Venus **flytrap*****,*** **drop** a couple of live ants or small insects into the container from time to time.

Is the "to feed the Venus flytrap" the subject of this sentence?

Why put a comma behind the flytrap?

Can I rewrite the sentence as like, to feed the Venus flytrap is to drop a couple of live ants or small insects into the container from time to time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sentence that uses the imperative.  The verb is "drop" and the subject is not written (it is implictly "you" in any imperative sentence)

There is an infinitve clause which is acting as an adverb. The clause "to feed the Venus Flytrap" tells us the purpose of dropping live ants into the container.  It is common to separate an adverbial phrase from the rest of the sentence.  In speech you would use intonation for the same effect.

You can move the adverbial phrase to the end:

> Drop a couple of live ants into the container to feed the Venus Flytrap.

(but the long phrase "into the container from time to time" works better at the end of the sentence)

There are lots of other ways of expressing the same idea.  You don't need to use an imperative, nor does it have to be in one sentence:

> You should drop live ants into the container from time to time. This will allow the Venus Flytrap to feed.